# A better way to replace emoticons in PHP?

Tags: php, emoticons, strtr

Right now I am using this function for emoticons:

```
function emoticons($text) {
        $icons = array(
                ':)'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
                ':-)'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
                ':D'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="icon_laugh" />',
                ':d'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="laugh" class="icon_laugh" />',
                ';)'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="wink" class="icon_wink" />',
                ':P'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':-P'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':-p'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':p'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':('    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" />',
                ':o'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
                ':O'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
                ':0'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="shock" class="icon_shack" />',
                ':|'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
                ':-|'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
                ':/'    =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
                ':-/'   =>  '<img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />'
        );
        return strtr($text, $icons);
    }
```

But if you enter a link the `:/` part of `http://` gets replaced:

[image]

Same with code (4 spaces in front of each line to create code box), but for some reason a simple `)` gets replaced (with a wink) as well:

[image]

Is there a better solution to this than replacing all of the icons like this? It obviously doesn't work good. I have searched on Google a lot and haven't found any better way. I also tried putting a space before each emoticon in the associative array above but that doesn't work if you just enter a :) without anything before it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function and then use word boundaries in the regular expression.

```
 foreach($icons as $icon=>$image) {
      $icon = preg_quote($icon);
      $text = preg_replace("~\b$icon\b~",$image,$text);
 }
```

You need to use word boundaries and not white space because this will take care of the start and end points to.  Needing a space before means that just a :) won't be found.

Comment: +1 for word boundaries - but in the case of 'http://www' wouldn't `http` be a word, and `/` a word boundary, so the `:/` would still get filtered?

Comment: actually, i take that back - +1 for [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote), that's awesome!

Comment: So I put this in my function instead of using `strtr()`? **Edit:** Hmm, for some reason no icons are being turned into images now. I wonder if there is a way to make no text emoticons turn into images in code boxes?

Comment: Gmail chat does it nicely. Do you know if they use regex or some other thing?

Comment: Gmail almost certainly does it with regular expressions but they probably do it at the javascript level rather than in php in between the two chatters if I had to guess.  There is one thing that maybe you can change to see if it works, instead of | as the bounding character for the regex try something which isn't in any of the emoticons.  Srry about that I changed my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: since you are using a tilde should pass it as the second parameter to preg_quote.   i.e. preg_quote($icon, '~');

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are slow for this if the text is big, as much as i like them, you should only insert an icon if it's surrounded by spaces, that way your users won't riot when trying to write urls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it will work or not, but I'd try to put some extra spaces like this:

```
function emoticons($text) {
    $icons = array(
            ' :) '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" /> ',
            ' :-) '   =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" /> ',
            ' :D '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="smile" class="icon_laugh" /> ',
            ' :d '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="laugh" class="icon_laugh" /> ',
            ' ;) '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="wink" class="icon_wink" /> ',
            ' :P '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" /> ',
            ' :-P '   =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" /> ',
            ' :-p '   =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" /> ',
            ' :p '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" /> ',
            ' :( '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" /> ',
            ' :o '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" /> ',
            ' :O '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" /> ',
            ' :0 '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="shock" class="icon_shack" /> ',
            ' :| '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" /> ',
            ' :-| '   =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" /> ',
            ' :/ '    =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" /> ',
            ' :-/ '   =>  ' <img src="/images/blank.gif" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" /> '
    );
    return strtr($text, $icons);
}
```

Comment: This method would work great if you make a tweak on the RETURN portion. return trim(strtr(" $text ",$icons));

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend two libraries:

Emojify: https://github.com/HallgrenNetworks/emojify

PHP Emoji: https://github.com/iamcal/php-emoji

These will deal with these cases for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think using [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.pcre.php) instead of just defining your emoticons. This could look like

```php
// replaces a :) when it is surrounded by whitespaces
return preg_replace('/\s:)\s/', '<img ...>', $text);
```