# very simple preg_replace not working

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
function emotify($text)
{
    $icons = array(
                ':)'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/happy.png" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
                ':-)'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/happy.png" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
                ':D'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/grin.png" alt="smile" class="icon_laugh" />',
                ':d'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/grin.png" alt="laugh" class="icon_laugh" />',
                ":'("    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/crying.png" alt="crying" class="icon_cry" />',
                ';('    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/crying.png" alt="crying" class="icon_cry" />',
                ':d'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/grin.png" alt="laugh" class="icon_laugh" />',
                ';)'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/wink.png" alt="wink" class="icon_wink" />',
                ':P'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':-P'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':-p'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':p'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
                ':('    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/sad.png" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" />',
                ':-('   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/sad.png" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" />',
                ':o'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
                ':O'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
                ':0'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shack" />',
                ':|'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
                ':-|'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
                ':/'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
                ':-/'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />'
        );

     foreach($icons as $icon=>$image) {
      $icon = preg_quote($icon, '/');
$return = preg_replace("/$icon/i", $image, $text);
      }
    return $return;
}
$posted = emotify($posted);
```

this is my code to change emoticons into images. it just returns
`Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/' on line 203`

how can I fix it?
EDIT: this is all of my code including the array which may be the problem why my code is not working. I'm not sure, but non of the answers have helped so I think that must be were the problem lies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A better way to replace emoticons in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658734/a-better-way-to-replace-emoticons-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having further established what you're doing through the comments, here is an answer using a DOM parser and a bit of cleverness:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($icons as $icon=>$image) {
  $textnodes = $xpath->query("//text()"); // get all text nodes
  foreach($textnodes as $node) {
    // the regex used here requires that there not be a non-space before it
    // in other words, it must be the first thing, or have a space before it
    while( preg_match("((?<!\S)".preg_quote($icon).")i",$node->nodeValue,$m,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
      $emote = $node->splitText($m[0][1]); // the offset is stored here
      $node = $emote->splitText(strlen($icon));
      // now replace the emote with the image:
      $img = $dom->createElement("img");
      $img->setAttribute("src",$image);
      // IMPORTANT: $image must be just the SRC, and NOT the entire HTML node
      $emote->parentNode->replaceChild($img,$emote);
    }
  }
}
// loadHTML puts the HTML into a document, we need to get it back out
$result = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
$result = substr($result,strlen("<body>"),-strlen("</body>"));
```

Now you may use `$result`, which all being well should have valid HTML including converted emotes.

Comment: so this is still in php

Comment: so if i put this code into my emotify function it should work?

Comment: Yes, provided you adjust your `$icons` array as mentioned in the code's comments.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNode::setAttribute()

Comment: Ah, my mistake, that should be `new DOMElement`, not `new DOMNode`.

Comment: Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Comment: I realised I used the same variable name twice. Notice the edited answer I used `$img` instead of the second `$image`.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'No Modification Allowed Error' Stack trace: #0 (215): DOMElement->setAttribute('src', '<img src="/imag...') #1 (227): emotify(':)') #2 {main} thrown  on line 215

Comment: I notice you didn't change your `$icons` array like I told you to. Each value should ONLY have the image's source, NOT the entire `<img src="...">`. That said, looks like the error is caused by the element not being associated with a document. Try replaceing `new DOMElement` with `$dom->createElement`, as in my newly edited answer.

Comment: it all works fine except if the user types two emoticons only the first is converted into an image @Kolink

Comment: make that two of the same type of emoticon

Comment: Hmm... okay, I've updated the second `splitText` line. It should correctly support there being more of the same emote.

Comment: Okay, I've rearranged the loops, so now it should re-evaluate the list of text nodes each time properly.

Comment: thankyou so much it looks to be working fine now if I have any problems i will comment here because I dont know how to PM people.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a slash in the value of `$icon`, so that you are actually calling

```
preg_replace( '/foo/bar/i', $image, $text )
```

which is a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg-quote) will NOT escape slashes unless you tell it that this is your chosen delimiter.

That being said, using PREG is WAY overkill.

Use [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/str-ireplace) instead.

Comment: Then you'll have to be a bit cleverer. Avoid using Smilie codes that may appear in legitimate text. Personally I prefer `=/` over `:/`. Of course, I'd also question whether you even *want* smilies. Are you making a chat? If not, you probably don't want them.

Comment: yes i am making a chat i stole the code in my question from here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658734/a-better-way-to-replace-emoticons-in-php

Comment: Consider replacing them in the JavaScript side. JavaScript can tell the difference between text and non-text much more easily than PHP can.

Comment: that wouldn't work because the chats get logged in a database and they get stripped of html tags in php

Comment: I have posted a new answer, featuring revised code considering what you have told me here.

Answer (score 2):

[**`preg_quote`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) actually has 2 arguments. 2nd optional argument can be the `regex delimiter` to be used in `preg functions`.

As per the mannual:

**`delimiter`**

> `If the optional delimiter is specified, it will also be escaped. This
>   is useful for escaping the delimiter that is required by the PCRE
>   functions. The / is the most commonly used delimiter.`

Use your code like this:

```
$icon = preg_quote($icon, '/');
$return = preg_replace("/$icon/i", $image, $text);
```

**UPDATE: Problem is that you're not initializing `$return` variable before start of foreach loop and always trying to replace in original `$text` variable itself.**

Have your foreach loop like this:

```
$return = $text;
foreach($icons as $icon=>$image) {
       $icon = preg_quote($icon, '/');
       $return = preg_replace("/$icon/i", $image, $return);
}
```

Comment: thats not working maybe it is my array i will post it in the question

Comment: @jordanzhninja: Edited further to allow multiple replacements in input e.g. this input should also work now: `" :D yey :)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function emotify($text)
{
    $icons = array(
        ':)'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/happy.png" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
        ':-)'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/happy.png" alt="smile" class="icon_smile" />',
        ':D'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/grin.png" alt="smile" class="icon_laugh" />',
        ':d'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/grin.png" alt="laugh" class="icon_laugh" />',
        ':\'('  =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/crying.png" alt="crying" class="icon_cry" />',
        ';('    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/crying.png" alt="crying" class="icon_cry" />',
        ';)'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/wink.png" alt="wink" class="icon_wink" />',
        ':P'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
        ':-P'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
        ':-p'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
        ':p'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/tounge.png" alt="tounge" class="icon_tounge" />',
        ':('    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/sad.png" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" />',
        ':-('   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/sad.png" alt="sad face" class="icon_sad" />',
        ':o'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
        ':O'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shock" />',
        ':0'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/shocked.png" alt="shock" class="icon_shack" />',
        ':|'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
        ':-|'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
        ':/'    =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />',
        ':-/'   =>  '<img src="/images/emoticons/straight.png" alt="straight face" class="icon_straight" />'
        );
    return str_replace(array_keys($icons), array_values($icons), $text);
}
```

Note that in this case it will be better to define two arrays.

Notice: this kind of search/replace must not be case-sensitive `:D  :d`
A laughing emoticon was duplicate.