# Website emoticons implementation

Tags: php, comments, emoticons

I'm building a website using PHP which supports commenting on posts. I want the users to be able to use smileys in their comments, such as `:) :D` etc. Now I want to know which is the best practice to implement them. I have only got this until now:

```
<?php
    str_replace(":)",'<img src="smiley.png" />',$comment);
?>
```

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658734/a-better-way-to-replace-emoticons-in-php?rq=1